# How to implement split transaction in Paypal?

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, development-environment, paypal-subscriptions

How to implement split transaction in Paypal? I done the module for one to one payment but did not get the valid code for split transaction.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For doing split transaction you need Adaptive payment method with the help of MPL library. Here is link provided by Paypal with step by step detail:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/

Comment: However, PayPal has discontinued the Adaptive Payment with MPL. You can use, but PayPal might not be much helping if you escalate the issue of MPL to them since this library has not been maintain since 2015.

Comment: Thanx  @amuroray , can you plz give me some brief description because i'm new with paypal or any payment gateway.

Comment: What is your business purpose and where are you located?